# htaccess to stop /_ after page name - not by base url want to achieve from htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I dont want to handle this by base URL using html and or by giving the full path I want to redirect to 404 if the user types a /_ after the page name...

If the user in the browser level types backslash did manage to do this.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*).php/$ /$1/ [R=404,L]
```

My Question is...........

IF the user in the browser level types for example after the web page name home.php a /_ then this gives a broken web page.

home.php/_
How to stop it from htaccess and if the user in the browser types home.php/_ then I need to stop this and direct to 404 just like to the backslash I did!

Please Help - appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)/.*$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This way the entry is corrected without the `/_`

Comment: Thank you so much I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: I tried the code you gave Mr.Croises, thank you so so so much it works perfectly. Good luck. God bless. Thank you again